# Meaning Behind Mapping from a Compact Subset to Another Set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose I tell you that a set, $A$, is compact and a subset of a metric space. This means that it is closed and bounded and that every sequence in set $A$ has a converging sub-sequence. Then I tell you that $f$ maps from set $A$ to set $B$. I would like someone to elaborate on the mapping from set $A$ to set $B$ from these sequences and sub-sequences. Does it mean that there are lists of numbers in set $A$ and $f$(each number) maps to a number in set $B$? Is it not "strange" for set $A$ to be characterized as many different sequences of numbers?

Thank you stackexchange community

Comment: $A$ is not *characterized* as many different sequences.  $A$ has **the property** that if you take any sequence *of elements of $A$*, then that sequence will have a convergent subsequence (and this property is called compactness).

Comment: Also, are the elements of $A$ *numbers*? Do you specifically mean that $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Closed and bounded is not necessarily equivalent to compact. It just happens to be in $\mathbb{R}^n$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345342/a-example-of-closed-and-bounded-does-not-imply-compactnesss-in-metric-space

Comment: @PatrickStevens he didn't necessarily imply equivalence, just that all compact sets are closed and bounded, which is true in metric spaces.

Comment: Does the main sequence in A also converge?

Comment: What do you mean by "main sequence"?

Comment: @Om yes, true. I interpreted "this means" as "this is equivalent to", but of course I was wrong to do so.

Comment: @OverSampled whats "the main sequence"?  If you're given a compact set, how do you find its "main sequence"?

Comment: By "main sequence" I mean not a sub-sequence of A but the list of numbers that characterizes A.

Comment: @OverSampled what makes you think that there is always such a list?

Comment: @PatrickStevens I think you interpreted "this means" correctly but failed to read the rest of the sentence: "this means that **it is closed and bounded and that every sequence in set A has a converging sub-sequence**"

Comment: @Om I'm not sure. Is A not characterized by a list of numbers? Can it be characterized by something else?

Comment: I think this should be happening in chat, because I get the impression @OverSampled has something a bit wrong in their fundamental understanding somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "characterized by a list of numbers"? A metric space - compact or not - is just a set of points, together with a distance function. By "sequence" do you mean "countable dense subset"? If so, yes, every compact metric space has a countable dense subset, and so the metric space is determined by the distances between points in that subset, and every point in the space is the limit of a (in fact, many) sequence of points from this dense subset.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I'm not sure how to start a chat without the "please start a chat" link, but it's a  good idea.

Comment: Can't be done except by a mod, it seems: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted

Comment: The layman's answer is to spam the chat a bit until it prompts you.

Comment: And by "chat" I mean "comment thread".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I think you're having some trouble picture what a map between metric spaces does to sequences. If so, maybe this helps:

If $f: A\rightarrow B$, then what $f$ does is, when fed an element of $A$, it spits out an element of $B$. On the face of things, $f$ doesn't have anything to do with sequences at all.

However, if I have a sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $A$, then I can "move this sequence over" to $B$ using $f$, in a natural way: just apply $f$ to each term to get $(f(a_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Note that I don't need any assumptions about $A$ and $B$ to do this - any time $A$ and $B$ are sets, and I have any function between them, I can use this function to move sequences from $A$ to $B$.

Now, if $A$ is a metric space, we can ask how $f$ might change sequences' properties. For instance, if $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, is $(f(a_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ also Cauchy? And so forth. In general, even if we assume $f$ is continuous, properties like Cauchyness are not conserved: for instance, as an exercise find a continuous function $f$ from $(0, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is order-preserving ($a<b\implies f(a)<f(b)$); then the sequence $({1\over 2}, {1\over 3}, {1\over 4}, . . .)$ is Cauchy, but its image under $f$ will not be.

However, if we make some additional assumptions on $A$, then continuous maps *do* preserve important properties of sequences - for instance, if we assume $A$ is *complete*, then if $(a_i)_{i\in\omega}$ is Cauchy, so will be $(f(a_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Note that compactness implies completeness.